# Ruby on Rails - "Reason: image not found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While creating a new directory for Ruby on Rails, I am getting this error:

> Reason: image not found - /Users/varma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin16/psych.bundle

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the code you are using?

Comment: I tried to open Ruby on Rails in Mac but unfortunately I got this error. Before I were running good without any error.

Comment: But however I figured it out, By removing all the gem files and installed from scratch and now it’s working.